# Symmetric matrix from a vector

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

There is a function `VectorToSymmetricMatrix` that does the following:

```
Statistics`Library`VectorToSymmetricMatrix[{1, 2, 3}, {5, 6, 7}, 3] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5 & 1 & 2 \\
 1 & 6 & 3 \\
 2 & 3 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I find it quite inconvenient to use because my data is differently ordered:

```
v={5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 7}
```

I am searching for a simple way to convert this vector to a symmetric matrix shown above.

There are similar posts, however, I could not find one addressing my problem. Please, try to provide a solution as simple and pedagogical as possible. I prefer to use documented functions even if the solution is slower.

A test case could be:

```
v = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 75 (75 + 1)/2}];
m = Table[UnpackUpTrg[vi], {vi, v}];
```

---

My current implementation is

```
ind[i_, j_] := If[i < j, i + j (j - 1)/2, j + i (i - 1)/2]
UnpackUpTrg[v_] := Module[{k},
  k = 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 Length[v]]);
  Table[v[[ind[i, j]]], {i, k}, {j, k}]
  ]
```

but it is a bit slow and procedural.

Comment: `v1=v[[{2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 6}]]`  gives he Order you want. and `Statistics`Library`VectorToSymmetricMatrix[v1[[1 ;; 3]], v1[[4 ;; 6]],
  3]` creates the matrix.

Comment: @DanielHuber Yes, but this was just an example of how results should look like. But the intended use case is given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
toSymmetricMat = Transpose[LowerTriangularize[#, -1]] + # & @
    PadRight[TakeList[#, Range[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 Length[#]])]]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
toSymmetricMat[{5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 7}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  5 & 1 & 2 \\
>  1 & 6 & 3 \\
>  2 & 3 & 7 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
toSymmetricMat[{5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 7, 3, 5, 6, 8}] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  5 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
>  1 & 6 & 4 & 5 \\
>  2 & 4 & 7 & 6 \\
>  3 & 5 & 6 & 8 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
SeedRandom[1]
rvec = RandomInteger[10, 7 (7 + 1)/2];
toSymmetricMat[rvec] // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  1 & 4 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
>  4 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 8 & 3 & 2 \\
>  7 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 2 & 6 \\
>  8 & 6 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 10 & 4 \\
>  1 & 8 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 5 \\
>  1 & 3 & 2 & 10 & 1 & 6 & 4 \\
>  0 & 2 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Update:** For versions 11.1 and older, replace `TakeList` with `` Internal`PartitionRagged ``:

```
toSymmetricMat2 = Transpose[LowerTriangularize[#, -1]] + # &@
  PadRight[Internal`PartitionRagged[#, Range[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + 8 Length[#]])]]] &;


And @@ (toSymmetricMat2[#] == toSymmetricMat[#] & /@ 
   {{5, 1, 6, 2, 3, 7}, {5, 1, 6, 2, 4, 7, 3, 5, 6, 8}, rvec})
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to try your code, but I found that I do not have the `TakeList` function. It was introduced in MA11.2, but I have MA11.1.1. Can you maybe suggest a solution using older functions?

Comment: @yarchik, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you, it is actually 10 times faster than my code and 3 times faster than my compiled code :). I will wait a little bit with accepting the answer, maybe someone will come up with a function that does not use undocumented functions, as explicitly asked in OP.